# Showing `$bountyAward$` instead of how much I offered in bounties

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I just went to my [offered bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal?tab=bounties) and saw this:

[image]

Something is not being parsed correctly it seems

Comment: Another #SubstitutionBug# strikes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, the joys of updating template languages.

Thanks for pointing this out, the latest deploy contains a fix for it.