# I've voted $q$ times on questions and $a$ times on answers?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web

> Of the votes cast, 45 were up-votes and 25 were down-votes. Undo voted on questions $q$ times and $a$ times on answers.

Seen on the mobile site; on the overview of my profile.

Pretty self-explanatory. It's borked!

[image: Screenshot: It is indeed.]

Comment: Possibly related bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190928/showing-bountyaward-instead-of-how-much-i-offered-in-bounties

Comment: Yep. They're probably missing some parenthesisis.

Comment: Missing $n$ free hand circles!

Comment: How many patches can the system take until Skeet breaks the concept of numbers completely? ;)

Comment: @sha Sorry - I'm on Mobile without the ability to draw freehand circles. GIMP no run on Mobile :(

Comment: Ah, [Add an Image Upload button to the Mobile Site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153551/add-an-image-upload-button-to-the-mobile-site) is for sissies ;-)

Comment: @Arjan I use the full site almost all of the time :|

Comment: @michaelb958 Pretty circles! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber MS Paint on Surface RT - one of the few things it's good for.

Comment: Not a dupe! Different issues!

Comment: @michaelb958 Paint.NET rulz!

Comment: @Undo same bug, different victims. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Real men use Paint. (**Real Programmers** use a hex editor, but I'm not that good.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was caused by (what I suspect is) a regression in some templating code.

The old version expects any identifier between two `$`s, the new version expects an identifier *of two or more characters*.  A fix for this went out with the latest build, thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Regression is better than oscillation!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That comment gave me an oscillation up my spine!

Comment: @Andrew I don't want to even imagine what code oscillation might cause! :D